# Whats the Red Dot in New Notification UI?

Tags: discussion

In screen shot below, what is this Red Dot next to `Low Quality Posts`. I am seeing this for the first time.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The red dot seems to indicate that there are more than 4-5 or more posts flagged as "Low Quality Posts" that need to be looked into by more people that have acquired the required score to be allowed to review them and cast their vote.

While the grey dot seem do indicate that there are 3-4 or fewer posts that need attention.

No dots means that there are no reviews queued for that specific topic.